# A statistics question: of to tell how much more likely to occur something is if it occured in the past.

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I have a basin of about 10 000 uniquely labeled items, of which some are periodically picked.

After 150 draws, we find that 100 different items have been picked. Naturally, some items have been picked up to 4 times.

So I have a breakdown that looks a bit like this:

Picked 0 times : 9900 items

Picked 1 time :80 items

Picked 2 times  :10 items

Picked 3 times :6 items

Picked 4 times : 4 items.

It’s obvious that if an item has been picked in the past, it’s more likely to be picked a second time in the future. I’d like to quantify this process. To say items that have already been selected are X% chance more likely to be picked a second time.
How to I compute such a figure.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why it is obvious that if an item has been picked once, it is more likely to be picked again in the future. Are you sampling with replacement? Otherwise, your intuition probably wouldn't hold if for example all the 10,000 items were different -- in that case, once you picked an item, it would have zero chance of reappearing.

Comment: @panini : Clearly it's with replacement since some items have been chosen more than once.

Comment: The picks seem to add up to $134$ rather than $150$

Comment: If you have 10,000 unique items, the probability for each being picked is the same at 0.01%. I'm assuming the items here are not actually unique, but this needs clarification on the original intent of the question

Comment: @MichaelHardy I see, I may have misunderstood the question -- I was imagining something like $n1$ red balls labelled $R1, R2, \ldots, R_{n1}$;  $n_2$ blue balls labelled $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_{n_2}$ and so on.

Comment: @Tal : It seems clear that these were not intended to be equally probable.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The question says 10,000 items, all unique. That leads to a very dull answer, and the perception that the OP didn't intend to ask it that way, exactly why I asked what the OP meant in the above comment

Comment: @Tal : See my answer below.

Comment: "It’s obvious that if an item has been picked in the past, it’s more likely to be picked a second time in the future": you probably mean it is *not* obvious ?

Comment: $100+2\cdot10+3\cdot6+4\cdot 4\ne150$. Review your data.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Probably he meant it _is_ obvious. Here's a simple example. Suppose $R$ is uniformly distributed in the interval between $0$ and $1,$ and $X_i\,\, i=1,2,3,\ldots$ are conditionally independent given $R,$ and the conditional probability that $X_i$ equals $1$ or $0,$ given $R,$ is $R$ or $1-R$ respectively. Then every time you observe a $1,$ it makes it more probable that you'll observe a $1$ next time. This is like that except instead of just two possible outcomes there are $10\,000. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: with zero a priori information on the random process, we do not assume any "obvious" dependence.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : In other words, the posted question was not expressed all that eloquently. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item $i\in\mathcal I$ has a probability $P_i$ of being chosen each time, and here I will assume the trials are independent. If we somehow know that there are exactly $10\,000$ items each of which has positive probability of being chosen each time, then for reasons that might require a long argument, I will assume the $10\,000$-tuple $(P_i)_{i\in\mathcal I}$ is uniformly distributed in the space of all $10\,000$-tuples for which $\sum_{i\in\mathcal I} p_i=1$ and for all $i\in\mathcal i,$ $p_i>0.$

For $i\in\mathcal I,$ let $x_i$ be the number of times item $i$ has been chosen so far in $150$ trials. Then the likelihood function is

$$
L(p_i : i\in \mathcal I) = \prod_{i\in\mathcal I} p_i^{x_i},
$$
and we know that $\sum_{i\in\mathcal I} x_i = 150,$ so most of the $x$s are $0.$

The prior probability distribution may be written as
$$
\text{constant} \times \prod_{i\,\in\,\mathcal I\,\smallsetminus \, \{j\}} dp_i.
$$
where $j$ is some distinguished element, since there are $10\,000-1$ degrees of freedom here. It doesn't matter which element is chosen for that role.

The posterior probability distribution is a constant times the likelihood function times the prior distribution; thus it is
$$
\text{constant}\times p_j^{x_j} \prod_{i\,\in\,\mathcal I\,\smallsetminus\,\{j\}} p_i^{x_i} \, dp_i.
$$
This is a Dirichlet distribution with parameters $(x_i+1 : i \in \mathcal I).$ The "constant" is
$$
\frac{\Gamma\left( \sum_{i\in\mathcal I} (x_i+1) \right)}{\prod_{i\in\mathcal I} \Gamma(x_i+1)}.
$$
The probability that item $k$ is chosen on the $151$st trial, given the results of the first $150$ trials, is then
\begin{align}
& \Pr( \text{$k$ is chosen on the 151st trial} \mid X_i= x_i \text{ for } i\in\mathcal I) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname E( P_k \mid X_i= x_i \text{ for } i\in\mathcal I) \\[8pt]
= {} & \text{expected value of a Beta distribution,} \\
& \text{since the marginals of a Dirichlet distribution} \\
& \text{are Beta distributions} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{x_k+1}{\sum_{i\in\mathcal I} (x_i+1)}.
\end{align}

This is actually a generalization of Laplace's problem on the probability that the sun will rise tomorrow.